# How would I specify a spring module validation “@RegExp” annotation using a regular expression from a .properties file or database

Tags: regex, spring-mvc

Here I define one field of my pojo file I want to get value from .properties file.
And I message is already comming from .properties file


`@RegExp(value = "((?=.\d)(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.[@#$%]).{6,20})")`

private String password;